# Using a pipe to send integers from n child to the parent (c/unix)

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe

I have to make a program that reads a number, then generates 10 children processes. Each child has to see the occurences of his index (the istance of the index used in the for in which they are created) in the actual number and send it back to the parent, so that he can see which one has the bigger number of occurences. I'll make an exempla to make it clear:
Let's say I input the number 012234555.
The first child (0) has 1 occurence.
The second (1) has 1.
The third (2) has 2.
and so on.
So the parent have to say that 5 is the number with the most occurences.

I'm using a pipe to send the occurences from the child to the parent, but it actually works only for the first child.What am i doing wrong?
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <sys/wait.h>  

#define N 10

int main (void)
{
    int i=0,max=0,j=0,tube[2],nbyte,w,occ,occv[10]={0},count=0;
    pid_t pid,my_pid,child_pid;
    char buffer[30],check;
    printf("Insert the nunmber: ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    my_pid=getpid();
    if (pipe(tube))
        {
            printf("\nError while creating the pipe!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    if ((pid=fork())<0)
        {
            printf("\nError while forking!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    else if (pid==0) //child
        {
            occ=0;
            close(tube[0]);
            check = (char)(((int)'0')+i);
            for (j=0;j<strlen(buffer);j++)
                if (check==buffer[j])
                occ++;
            printf("I'm the child %d (pid %d), my occurence is %d\n",i,getpid(),occ);
            if (occ>0)
                {
                    nbyte=write(tube[1],&occ,sizeof(int));
                    printf("I'm the child %d and i wrote %d bytes (the actual integer is %d)\n",getpid(),nbyte,occ);
                }
            exit(i);
        }
    else //parent
        {
            close(tube[1]);
            nbyte=read(tube[0],&(occv[i]),sizeof(int));
            printf("I'm the parent pid(%d) and i read %d bytes (the actual integer is %d)\n",getpid(),nbyte,occv[i]);
            if (occv[i]>max)
                max=i;
        }
    }
    while(wait(&w)>0);
    printf("I'm the parent (pid %d) and the number with max occurence is %d\n",getpid(),max);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first pass through the loop, you close tube[0] in the parent. It is therefore not available to children on subsequent passes through the loop. It's not actually necessary to close it at this point.

You also aren't particularly taking advantage of forking -- you don't fork your second child until the first child has terminated -- but I'm not sure what the point of this exercise is, so that may not be a problem.

Comment: Yeah i didn't think about that!That totally fixed the problem!
I just had to move both closing the pipe in writing and reading ten times out of the loop.That should fix the forking "issue too if i'm not mistaken, since the parent now loops the forks before actually stopping to read, is that  right?

Comment: It should. Side point: never use scanf("%s"); use scanf("%30s").